# Why this "checked" doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is the code :

```
    $('#checkBoxContact1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#chbBox1').attr('checked') == true)
            $('#chbBox1').attr('checked', 'false');
        else $('#chbBox1').attr('checked', 'true');
    });
```

I call this when I click on a link. But in fact seems that it doesnt works...

maybe I should use :checked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.prop()` and more important, **do not quote** boolean values.

For boolean *attributes* the pure existence matters. `checked=""`, `checked="no"`, `checked="false"` all result in the element being checked.
To un-check an element through the attribute you'd have to use `.removeAttr('checked')`.

However, you can use the *property* which is an actual boolean. So `.prop('checked', true_or_false)` will do what you want. Actually you could even use `.attr('checked', true_of_false)` since jQuery 1.6.1 but using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` is a bit faster since it doesn't need to check if it's actually a property you are trying to set instead of an attribute.

Comment: +1 `.prop()`s to you. Would +1 again if i could for the boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
1. $('#chbBox1').attr('checked', ''); // for false
2. $('#chbBox1').attr('checked', 'checked'); //for true
```

Upto jQuery-1.5.2 #1 is working.

In jQuery- 1.6 its taking as true.

Comment: I believe that `$('#chbBox1').attr('checked', '');` equates to *true* not *false* (resulting in `<input type="checkbox" checked="" />`).

Comment: @thiefmaster and @David Thomas upto Jquery 1.5.2 it is false, but i checked with the latest verison...its not working any reason...